# How to read/write/change jQuery UI slider with Selenide?

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, jquery-ui, selenide

I would like to test how jQuery UI slider

[image]

works with Selenide. I tried

```
$("#L3, #numeric-ui-slider-handle").sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT);
```

but this failed with

```
Invalid element state: element not interactable
```

If activate element by hand and press right arrow key it works.

Either I need to send keys globally, not targeted to element, or I need to set it's value somehow directly.

Comment: Can we have HTML as well if applicable ?

Comment: @cruisepandey it's jQuery UI, it is created with Javascript with `$("something").slider(...)` I can't guarantee how is it rendered with HTML, see https://jqueryui.com/slider/

Comment: in case if it's just testing the slider positioning, you can see `style="left: 62%;` has been updating when you move the slider.

Comment: This may be done via actions class, I feel.

Comment: @cruisepandey suppose I want to move slider to next position to the left, how to compute a percentage? May be I can call `value` methid of slider object from Selenide/Selenium somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Here is everything you need to move slider, and test it using `%` like I did below :-

```
@Test
public void testJQuerySlider() throws InterruptedException {
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/slider/");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.className("demo-frame")));
    System.out.println("Inside iframe");
    WebElement slider = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div#slider span")));
    slider.click();
    String sliderPosition = slider.getAttribute("style");
    System.out.println(sliderPosition);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    for (int i = 0; i<=10; i++) {
        action.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    WebElement newslider = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div#slider span")));
    String newSliderPosition = newslider.getAttribute("style");
    System.out.println(newSliderPosition);
}
```